# SQL How to add int value to existing datatable cell value?

Tags: sql

Hello guys I have a problem I have int value and I have datatable which is not empty. I want to add my int value like 13 to datatable cell value which is like 236. Could anyone share a code which solves this problem I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will add `13` to the cell value in all rows:

```
UPDATE datatable
SET cellValue = cellValue + 13
```

If you only want to do it to certain rows, add a `WHERE` clause that selects the rows you want:

```
UPDATE datatable
set cellValue = cellValue + 13
WHERE someOtherColumn = 10
```

Comment: Thx it works I could do it by myself actually I was thinking that cell must be converted to int first and declared... But I forgot that that column is only int.